# how to show all label content?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm new with kivy and creating a game generator that generates the number of random encounters based on how many enemies the user may input. But in the final part, only one enemy is shown even if I input more than one.

How can I make the label, show all its content?

```
import random
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1

        self.info_grid = GridLayout()
        self.info_grid.cols = 2

        self.info_grid.add_widget(Label(text="Numero de inimigos:"))
        self.Inimigos = TextInput()
        self.info_grid.add_widget(self.Inimigos)
        self.add_widget(self.info_grid)

        self.Gerador = Button(text="Gerar", font_size=40)
        self.Gerador.bind(on_press=self.Gerar)
        self.add_widget(self.Gerador)

        self.show_inimigos = (Label(text="Clique para gerar"))
        self.add_widget(self.show_inimigos)

    def Gerar(self, instance):

        int_inimigos = int(self.Inimigos.text)

        racas = ["HUMANO", "ELFO", "ANÃO", "HOBBIT", "LAGARTÃO", "LEONINO", "NEZUMI"]
        classe = ["APPRENTICE", "FIGHTER", "KNIGHT", "BERSERKER", "FENCER", "NINJA", "HOPLITE", "BEAST TAMER",
                  "DRAGON TAMER", "ARCHER", "ROUGE", "DOLL MASTER", "WARLOCK", "MAGE", "ACOLYTE", "MONK", "CLERIC",
                  "BARD", "WARLORD", "SHAMAN", "DRUID", "SPEAKER", "MERCHANT", "ALCHEMIST", "BLACKSMITH", "CHEF"]
        elemento = ["FIRE", "AIR", "WATER", "EARTH", "LIGHT", "DARK"]

        for i in range(int_inimigos):
            escolha_raca = random.choice(racas)
            escolha_classe = random.choice(classe)
            escolha_elemento = random.choice(elemento)
            encontro = (escolha_raca + ' : ' + escolha_classe + '  -  ' + escolha_elemento)

            self.show_inimigos.text = (encontro + "\n")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I think it some problem with the `Gerar` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(int_inimigos):
    escolha_raca = random.choice(racas)
    escolha_classe = random.choice(classe)
    escolha_elemento = random.choice(elemento)
    encontro = (escolha_raca + ' : ' + escolha_classe + '  -  ' + escolha_elemento)

    self.show_inimigos.text = (encontro + "\n")
```

Looks like you always set `self.show_inimigos.text` to the value for the most recent `encontro` from the iteration.

Do something like `self.show_inimigos.text += encontro + '\n'`.

Comment: i've tried this before, but it continuously adds more and more encounters and do not reset

Comment: I've done a line of code that resolved that problem! ```self.show_inimigos.text = ""```
Thanks for the help